# Filling an array declared with <?> type

Tags: java, arrays, generics, wildcard

I was reading Java Generics and I ran into a problem with an array filling.

```
Gen<?> array[] = new Gen<?>[10];

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = (Integer) (i+3);
    }
    for (int i  = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Compiler says this error: incompatible types: Integer cannot be converted to gen.

The question is, how to fill or inform the array what I'm going to put inside in this situation? Thank you.

Comment: That's because `Integer` is not a `Gen`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you know that you're going to put integers in the array, just declare the array as `Gen`.  If you need more flexibility, use collections instead of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your requirement, but below code might help you to understand how it works -

**DataTypes.java**

```
public class DataTypes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gen<?> array[] = new Gen<?>[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = new Gen<Integer>(i);
        }
        for (int i  = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i].getData() + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

**Gen.java**

```
class Gen<T> {
    T data;

    public Gen(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```